# A homeomorphism maps boundary in boundary?

Tags: general-topology

Let $U$ and $V$ be two topological spaces and let $A \subset U$ be a topological subspace of $U$ and let $B \subset V$ be a topological subspace of $V$.

Let $f:A \to B$ be a homeomorphism

I would like to know if is it true that
$$
a \in \delta A \Rightarrow f(a) \in \delta B
$$

($\delta X =$ boundary $X$)

Comment: If $a\in\delta A$ but $a\notin A$ then $f(a)$ is undefined.

Comment: To avoid the problem raised in a comment and an answer, you should let $f: U \to V$ be a continuous function such that $f|_A$ is a homeomorphism $A \to f(A) = B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following statements are equivalent, given a map $f: A\rightarrow B$, $A\subset U$ and $B\subset V$ topological spaces:

1. the map is continuous
2. the preimage of the family of the open sets in $V$ is contained in the family of the open sets in $U$.
3. the preimage of the family of the neighborhoods of a point is contained in the family of the neighborhoods of any preimage of the point.
4. Being a boundary point of a set for a point and a set in the domain of the map is an invariant property under the map.

Hope this help. Note also that homeomorphism is not needed.

---

the fourth point means:

4'. Given a point and a set both in the domain of the map, if the point is a boundary point of the set the image of the point is a boundary point of the image of the set under the map

Comment: Exuse me @trying, can you explane the point 4. better. thanks

Comment: @Matey Math I edited the answer. See there. I listed those equivalences in that order to let you see the proof. Also note that with the fourth point you have a positive answer to your problem, a bit generalized: Given a point and a set both in the domain of the map with the point being a boundary point of the set then the image of the point is a boundary point of the image of the set under the map if and only if the map is continuous. Let me know whether you need further explaination.

Comment: OK @trying thanks so much for helping me, you solved an important question for me.

Comment: @Matey Math This explains better than anything why continuity is of the utmost importance in engineering:no other than continuous functions gives no false-positive results. When measurement value processing through a continuous function gives results that are within a fixed tolerance however you fixed it, it is certain that exists a tolerance in the measurement value space which those measurement values that produced those results are within. You will never have falsely acceptable computed results from unacceptable measured values iff the computation is through a continuous function evaluation

Comment: I guess I am not understanding something properly.

Consider for instance the sine function with the usual topology on both sides (obviously continuous).

Consider the set $[0,2\pi]$. Zero is a boundary point of the set that you have considered on the domain, but its image (zero again) does not lie in the boundary of the image set $[-1,1]$...

Answer (score 5):

This is an example in which you won't have the problem of well definiteness of  other answers. Take

$U=\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual topology,

$V= \mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology,

$A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:y=0\}$,

$B=V,$

$f:A\to B$ as $f(x,0)=x.$

Comment: In this example, $\delta A=A,$ but the image of any point of A lies in the interior of B. So the answer is no.

Comment: $\partial A$ is with respect to the topology on U. In fact, if $A$ is a subspace of U, always $\partial A=\emptyset$ with respect to the topology of  $A$

Comment: I think you have the wrong concept of boundary point. There is a result which states that $\bar{A}= \partial A \cup int(A),$ but that does not implies that $\partial A = \bar{A}\setminus A.$ Acording to your definition, all closed sets have empty boundary, and this is just not true

Comment: thanks @Magnusseen for your answer

Answer (score 2):

In general, you don't even know if $f(a)$ is defined, since you do not know if $\delta A\subset A$.

For example, take $U=V=\mathbb R$, $A=B=(0,1)$ (standard topology, of course), and $f:A\to B$ defined as $f(x)=x$.

Then, $0\in\delta A$ and $f(0)$ is not defined.

Comment: thanks @5xum for your answer

Answer (score 2):

In general $f$ does not extend to $\partial A\setminus A$ so the question does not make much sense.

For instance, consider $A=(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)\subset U=\Bbb R$ and $B=V=\Bbb R^2$ with $f(x)=(x,\tan x)$.

If $f$ is the restriction of some continuous function $\tilde f$ defined on some neighborhood containing $\bar A$ then certainly $f(\partial A)\subseteq\bar B$.

Comment: thanks @AdLibitum for your answer